# How to automate a stored query and update/store the output of a stored query?

Tags: oracle, plsql, compilation

The objective of this automation is to run a couple of select count(*) queries in each row and update/store the result into the rows with respect to the queries. After storing the result into each row, it should proceed on to the next row and until the end of the table. It also should take into consideration if there is no select queries in either of the rows.

For example, there are a total of 4 columns: 
a) stored query ( ie. select count(cust) from customers_savings where saving>=‘’;) 
b) stored query of another table (ie. select count(cust) from customers_spendings where spending>=‘’;) 
c) stores the returned output from a, 
d) stores the returned output from b

Would greatly appreciate if there is a template or guideline that I can follow closely with. 
Currently using oracle plsql v17.4.

Thanks

Comment: What about some example-data? What should be selected? Where should it be stored?

Comment: For example, there are a total of 4 columns: a) stored query ( ie. select count(*) from customers_savings where saving>=‘’;)  b) stored query of another table (ie. select count(*) from customers_spendings where spending>=‘’;) c) stores the returned output from a, d) stores the returned output from b.

Comment: How should this operation be triggered?

Comment: For loop. Declare>begin>for cur in(select_stmt)>loop>begin>select stmt into v1, select stmt into v2>execute immediate v1 into op1, v2 into op2, update col(c,d)=op1,op2>commit>end

Comment: @DingyangLim Don't post code as comment. Please move the example-data and the example-code to your question. Have a look at my answer: Feel free to copy the Create-Table and the example-data for bette readability of your question.

Comment: Hi Kara, thanks so much it really did help so much, the logic flow provided was easy to understand. I'm new here so I was not sure but thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to mark my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Create Table

You could have provided this one ;)

```
CREATE TABLE TABLETEST
(
  QUERY1   VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR),
  RESULT1  NUMBER,
  QUERY2   VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR),
  RESULT2  NUMBER
);
```

#### Sample-Data

You should have provided these ;)

```
INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL', 0, 'SELECT 2 FROM DUAL', 0);
INSERT INTO TABLETEST VALUES('SELECT 3 FROM DUAL', 0, 'SELECT 4 FROM DUAL', 0);
```

#### Run the queries

```
declare
    tmpResult1 NUMBER;
    tmpResult2 NUMBER;
begin
    FOR i IN (SELECT query1, query2 FROM TABLETEST) -- loop through every row
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('query1: "' || i.query1 || '"'); -- let's have a look, what we got back from our select
        dbms_output.put_line('query2: "' || i.query2 || '"');

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE i.query1 INTO tmpResult1; -- executor out select-statement
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE i.query2 INTO tmpResult2;

        dbms_output.put_line('tmpResult1: ' || tmpResult1); -- let's have a look at our results
        dbms_output.put_line('tmpResult2: ' || tmpResult2);  

        UPDATE TABLETEST SET RESULT1 = tmpResult1, RESULT2 = tmpResult2 WHERE QUERY1 = i.query1 AND QUERY2 = i.query2; -- Store the results into the table.
    END LOOP;
end;
```

#### Review Result

```
SELECT * FROM TABLETEST;
```